# issue with loops in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am facing issues with my query:

```
select week_number
    ,year
from accounting_calender
where week_number<=3
and week_number>3-6
and year=2013
```

Here in this query I'm passing the week_number `3` and year `2013` through my reporting tool.

I'm getting the following output:

```
| Week_number | year |
----------------------
|    3        | 2013 |
|    2        | 2013 |
|    1        | 2013 |
```

But here in my accounting calender table I returned entries for 2012 too.

So here I'm subtracting `-6`, so it has to go to previous year weeks also.

I am looking for something like below output:

```
| Week_number | year |
----------------------
|   51        | 2012 |
|   52        | 2012 |
|   53        | 2012 |
|    3        | 2013 |
|    2        | 2013 | 
|    1        | 2013 |
```

I have read-only access.

Comment: How can week_number be <= 3 *and* > 3?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Maybe it's irrational! :)

Comment: @JNK YOU'RE irrational! :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Maybe because it says `3-6`?

Comment: @mellamokbtheWise so week_number > -3? This is more rational?

Comment: @mellamokbtheWise also when editing questions, please make edits as substantial as possible. Fixing code formatting but ignoring things like `iam` just means someone else is going to have to perform an additional edit.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Alrighty :)

Comment: @mellamokbtheWise --- here why i am subtracting with -6 is to get last 6 week's data.. the above query is working fone for week_number greater than 6. when the week_number is 6 its not working fine. if i give week_number less than 6, for values 5,4,3,2,1 in 2012 and instead 0f 0 it should go to 53 in 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a special case where the previous 6 weeks cross a year boundary:

```
select
  week_number,
  year
from
  accounting_calender
where
  (week_number > @week-6 and week_number <= @week and year=@year)
or
  (week_number > @week-6+53 and year=@year-1)
```

If `@week >= 6`, then the second condition will always be `> 53` so it will have no effect.  However, if `@week < 6`, then the second condition will be `52`, `51`, etc. for the previous year.

Comment: Caveat: I'm assuming every year has exactly `53` numbered weeks.

Comment: +1 Doesn't obfuscate the indexes, and your caveat should pass until 2028.

Answer (score 1):

Converting your weeks and years into dates will make it much easier to perform additions to your date range:

```
DECLARE @Week_Number INT
DECLARE @Year INT
DECLARE @WeeksToGet INT

SET @Week_Number = 3
SET @Year = 2013
SET @WeeksToGet = 6

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

SET @EndDate = DATEADD(WEEK, @Week_Number, DATEADD(YEAR, @Year - 1900, 0))
SET @StartDate= DATEADD(WEEK, -6, @EndDate)

select
    week_number,
    year
from accounting_calender
where 
    DATEADD(WEEK, week_number, DATEADD(YEAR, year - 1900, 0)) between
    @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

However, note that this will obfuscate any indexes that you have on `week_number` and `year`.  If this is a concern, you might consider changing these columns into a `DATE` type so that you can avoid having to convert the two columns into one date.

### [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/361b3/1)